# Post method not allowed on Django Rest Framework

Tags: django

I'm working on a small project using Django Rest Framework and VueJS, i have a small bug after sending my POST request i get **405 POST Method Not Allowed**, i don't know why since my request url is `/contact/create/`

This is my code :

```
class ContactView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        serializeObject = ContactSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializeObject.is_valid():
            serializeObject.save()
            contactObject = Contact.objects.all()
            contactSerializer = ContactSerializer(contactObject, many=True)
            return Response(contactSerializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializeObject.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My Axios Code :

```
getAPI.post('contact/create/', this.form).then((response) => {
                this.$emit('fetchContact')
            }).catch((error) => {

            })
```

Comment: Are you sure the url is `/contact/create/`? It is not only `/contact/` and called with POST method?

Comment: @Tiki yes you can double check my Question   ( updated )

Comment: A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create().

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing /create/ at the end, and keeping my request as POST